# PHP not processed when Stash parses conditionals in the same template

Tags: templates, stash, php

I've got a template with PHP enabled and set to `On Output`, and *any PHP at all* is getting commented and printed, without being processed, in the HTML.

Template (simplified):

```
{embed=".header"}

{exp:stash:set name="some_value" parse_conditionals="yes" parse_tags="yes"}{if 'something' == 'somethingelse'}y{/if}{/exp:stash:set}

<div>
    <?php echo 'foo'; ?>
</div>

{embed=".footer"}
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Oh the Confusion</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <!--<?php echo 'foo'; ?>-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Other templates use Stash and conditionals, many use PHP, and this is the only one that combines both Stash (parsing conditionals) and embedded PHP. Caching is not an issue here. This looks like a friendly, intentional thing since the PHP obviously isn't plainly visible to the viewer, but why is this happening?

ExpressionEngine 2.5.5 with a bajillion addons that I can list if it's helpful.

**Note: I've simplified my question after figuring out how to ask it better with the help of Lisa Wess. This one seems brief and cheeky because I'll be answering it myself for posterity.**

Comment: What is your template type, Matt?

Comment: Sorry, not the code, though that may help - but the type.  HTML? CSS? Static?  I'm actually wondering if it's somehow set to the latter. :)

Comment: I just realized I answered the wrong question. It's an EE Template, "Web Page".

Comment: If you can isolate the PHP out a bit - I think getting this to the bare minimum code that works might help. Then you can add things back until it breaks and figure it out that way.  With how the template is set up, you're going to have to reduce and isolate to figure this out, I think.

Comment: What a sensible idea! When the PHP is inside `{if member_group == 1}` it has this problem. Removing the conditional somehow makes it okay again. Does that make any sense? (I've tried variations like `{if "{member_group}" == 1}` etc to no avail.)

Comment: Not particularly.  Can you add the absolute minimum code to reproduce to your original post? Either directly or via pastie or some such?  Also maybe try group_id instead of member_group, or logged_in_member_group.  :)

Comment: Let me keep whittling it down. Thanks for the wildly fast help, Lisa.

Comment: My pleasure, though I am about to slow down as I need some coffee. ;)  Please keep us updated! Curiouser and curiouser, you know?

Comment: Got it! It is, without question, the presence of a conditional in one `{exp:stash:set}` line that throws PHP parsing in the whole template. Doesn't work: http://wrkcpt.com/code/1m3Y100C1C44. Works: http://wrkcpt.com/code/0L1W1q08360L

Comment: Hrm.  You know, if you can re-phrase with a more succint, clear example, I think it would probably get you more answers.  Though based on this: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq#questions I think I'd recommend re-titling and updated the body text.  :)

Comment: I think I was hoping for an "oh that's obvious!" kind of answer but what I really need is to do some more diligent testing to ask a better question. Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: My pleasure, Matt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You'll need to turn your PHP into a plugin or embed it in a sub-template.**

You could have saved yourself a lot of time if you'd noticed that Mark Croxton himself [pointed out that Stash doesn't parse PHP](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/7166#25166).